# Algebraic Dual and topological dual

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

We know that the Topological Dual of a vector space is strictly included in the algebraic dual. It mean that there are linear functional that are not continuous. In my course we construct the topological dual as follow : Let $\mathcal B$ a Banach space and $\mathcal B^*$ it's dual. Let $\mathcal T$ the thicker topology on $\mathcal B$ s.t. linear functional are continuous. We call $(\mathcal B,\mathcal T)$ the topological dual of $\mathcal B$.

**Q1)** Isn't it the weak topology of $\mathcal B$ instead of the dual topological ?

**Q2)** For me the dual topological is $\{f\in \mathcal B^*\mid f\text{ is continuous wrt the strong topology of }\mathcal B\}$. Do you agree ?

Comment: For q2, the topological dual depends on the topology you impose on the original space. The dual induced by the strong topology is one such dual, but it isn’t the only one.

Comment: The definition of $\cal B^*$ is unclear. You write "its dual" one sentence after acknowledging there is more than one. So which one is it?

Comment: $B^*$ it's the "algebraic dual" (it's unique, isn't it ?)@AsafKaragila

Comment: The algebraic dual is *much* larger in cardinality (in all infinite dimensional cases), so it is definitely not the weak topology. Not to mention that if you want all functional to be continuous, then for any choice of Hamel basis you need all the functionals which separate one basis element from the rest. Off the cuff, this restriction alone should end up with something akin to trivial or discrete topology. Neither of which you'd actually want to have.